# Azure Devops Download Secure File

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, salesforce, azure-pipelines

I am facing an issue wherein I uploaded a server.key in Download Secure File utility but in my pipeline, it is treating it as D:a_tempserver.key - when I call it in my task using echo $(server.secureFilePath). Any idea what could be the issue?

Error:
ERROR running auth:jwt:grant:  We encountered a JSON web token error, which is likely not an issue with Salesforce CLI. Here’s the error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\1\s\a_tempserver.key'

Answer (score 0):

In your current situation, we recommend you can use the `$(Agent.TempDirectory)/server.key` instead of the `$(server.secureFilePath)`. In the auzre devops, if we upload the secure file to pipeline, then it will put the file in the temp directory not under the source directory.
Here are some screenshots about my test, hope this will help you.

The Secure File directory:
[image]

The result of $(Agent.TempDirectory):
[image]